Streamlabs api 2.0 Uauthorized HTTP
currently i have this problem with stremlabs, I am trying to integrate a 3rd party donation service which will hit the streamlabs donations in order to augment the value there.
import requests
import datetime

API_ACCESS_TOKEN = "MY API ACCESS TOKEN"
# FROM https://streamlabs.com/dashboard#/settings/api-settings

url = "https://streamlabs.com/api/v2.0/donations"

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {API_ACCESS_TOKEN}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Donation data (replace with actual values)
donation_data = {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "message": "Thanks for the stream!",
    "identifier": "john.doe@example.com",
    "amount": 10.00,
    "currency": "USD",
    "created_at": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=donation_data)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Donation created successfully!")
        print(response.text)
    elif response.status_code == 400:
        print("Error creating donation:")
        print(response.text)
    else:
        print(f"Unexpected status code: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.text)

Unfortunatelly 2 hrs of debugging could not figure out why I recieve 401 Unauthorized
Unexpected status code: 401
Unauthorized.

